# PHP8 mail function adding space prefixes to headers

Tags: php, email, php-8

I just upgraded from PHP 7.4 to 8.0.  All of the sudden outgoing mails are getting spaces prefixed to the custom headers.

Here's the code:

```php
$headers = [
    'From: Somebody <somebody@example.com>',
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"',
];
mail('foo@example.com', 'Subject', 'Body', implode("\n", $headers));
```

A message that came in before the upgrade looked like this:

```
To: foo@example.com
Subject: Subject
From: Somebody <somebody@example.com>
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Message-Id: <E1n1vlx-0002C5-FC@hostname>

Body goes here
```

After the upgrade, the same code sends a message which looks like this for the receiver:

```
From: somebody@example.com
X-Google-Original-From: Somebody <somebody@example.com>
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
To: somebody@example.com
Subject: Subject
Message-Id: <E1n20bv-0007st-Eh@hostnme>

Body goes here
```

The Content-Type header is getting a space added to the beginning and thus mail clients are ignoring it.  exim4 doesn't have any logs of the full outgoing message so I'm not sure where to turn next.

Comment: Try using `\r\n` instead of `\n` for your implode -- the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321) explicitly specifies that as the line terminator.

Comment: Boom, there it is.  Add that as an answer and grab some acceptance points

Comment: I'm outside of my comfort zone with PHP, but having encountered [what looks to be] this issue in Drupal/CiviCRM, a workaround there was to alter the outbound email settings to 'Sendmail' rather than 'mail()'. Hopefully that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\r\n` instead of `\n` for your implode -- [RFC5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321) explicitly specifies CRLF as the line terminator. I notice that Gmail is adding this `X-Google-Original-From` header, between the two header lines that you specified:

```
From: somebody@example.com
X-Google-Original-From: Somebody <somebody@example.com>
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

I'll wager that the space is an artifact of Google trying to insert this line between two of yours, but not really two of yours, because incorrect line endings.

Comment: Alternatively, you can format the array in the format accepted by `mail()` and let PHP handle the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If your codebase is too large to fix all the code that generates email headers, you can work around the problem by changing your PHP configuration.

https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8086

In php.ini, change your sendmail_path to be:

`'/usr/bin/dos2unix -u|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'`

dos2unix will sort out the line endings and make them look how PHP 7 used to be. This script is not installed by default so you will need to install it with:

`sudo apt install dos2unix` (debian, ubuntu, etc)

It looks like future versions of PHP will have an .ini setting you can toggle (`mail.mixed_lf_and_crlf`) but it'll be a while before that becomes available.

Answer (score -2):

I think the $headers shouldn't be an array, just use simple string. you can see the example #2 here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: It _is_ a string, that's what `implode()` does.

Comment: sorry I don't see your implode. have u try `implode("\r\n",$headers)` \r\n is for new line in windows as for \n in new line in linux

Comment: exim4 isn't available for Windows